# Decryption for mono alphabetical substitution cipher in c

Tags: c

```
int main(void) {

    char plain[6] = "lorem";
    char cipher[27] = "nbajyfowlzmpxikuvcdegrqsth";
    int length = strlen(plain);
    char encrypted_text[6] = "pkcyx";

    /*encryption*/
    for (int i = 0 ; i < length ; i++) {
        plain[i] = cipher[plain[i] - 97];
        //printf("%c", plain[i]);
    }

    /*decryption*/
    for (int i = 0 ; i < length ; i++) {
        encrypted_text[i] = cipher index of encryted text.... how to write this... 
        eg: cipher index of o is 6 (0-n ,1-b, 2-a, 3-j, 4-y, 5-f, 6-o) ... i want this index so i + 97 will decrypt the msg  
        //printf("%c", plain[i]);
    }
}
```

May I know how do I get the cipher index of a encrypted letter?

Answer (score 0):

`plain[i] = cipher[plain[i] - 97];` overwrites plain, shouldn't you be writing to `encrypted_text`?  In addition, `plain[i] - 97` is not likely to be a valid index into the cipher array.

`encrypted_text[i] = cipher index of encrypted text....` is just wrong, you should be decrypting `encrypted_text`.

Decryption of a substitution cipher requires that you know the cipher code and reverse whatever operations were performed on the plain text, using that code.  In your case, the initial encryption operations are just invalid C code.

Comment: @ jwdonahueThanks for the reply!    
I ran this on visual studio code, output :  pkcyx (This would then be encrypted.) 


    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>

    int main(void) {

    char plain[6] = "lorem";
    char cipher[27] = "nbajyfowlzmpxikuvcdegrqsth";
    int length = strlen(plain);

    /*encryption*/

        for (int i = 0 ; i < length ; i++) {
            plain[i] = cipher[plain[i] - 97];
            //printf("%c", plain[i]);
        }
        printf("%s",plain);
    }

Comment: If given 

plain = "pkcyx";

cipher[27] = "nbajyfowlzmpxikuvcdegrqsth";

To decrypt this i could only think of using the index number of cipher of which the letter represents and + 97 to reach the decimal of the original letter.  for this case p is in cipher[11] and 11 + 97 will give me 108 which is the original letter "l" (lowercase letter of L).


But i do not know how to write that in code. Could you give me some hints on the implementation part?